# Using oauth and twitter to authenticate actions with php

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Im learning about oauth and i have my application setup and im able to authenticate my account and get my token, but im curious how i use this to authenticate an API call?

Where before im using

```
http://username:password@twitter.com/whatever.xml
```

What do i do now with my token to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have a valid access token key and secret you can access the protected resources or your API.
To do this you have to 'sign' your request with the information you have (access token, secret, consumer key, secret and other oauth artifacts) and send it via HTTP.
http://oauth.net/core/1.0#signing_process

You must have a signing method in your OAuth client API, which should just take the Request object and sign it for you, even send the request over HTTP for you.